# How to save a model table programmatically in yii2

Tags: model, yii2-advanced-app

I want to add a new row in a table (`ticket`) from a controller (`ProductController`) create action, I have added below code :

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    ...
    $modelpricing = new Ticket;
    $modelpricing->price = $price;
    $modelpricing->available = $available;
    $modelpricing->save(); 
    ...
}
```

But this code is not creating row in `ticket` table.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propably you have some validation rules in your model. When calling method `save()` - youre validating user input.

Try to check, what is the problem by adding:

```
if(!$modelpricing->save()) {
   var_dump($modelpricing->errors);die;
}
```

You will see what is the problem, fix it and that's all ;)

Comment: Thanks, I was assigning a integer value to available, while it is expecting in  string as the table column is `enum` type.

Comment: No problem! ;) Have a nice day!